# Fetch large result from Facebook Graph API paging in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the friendlists field from FB graph API in my android app. As it has a large number of result I am getting a paging in the end of the result.

```
"friendlists": {
    "data": [
      ....data
    ],
    "paging": {
      "next": <next page URL>
    }
  }
```

How do I access the next set of result in my app.
Following is the code to fetch the first set of result.

```
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "friendlists");
final GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me");
        graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        GraphResponse response = graphRequest.executeAndWait();

        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
        try {
            friendList = json.getJSONObject("friendlists").getJSONArray("data");
// Where I want to fetch the next set of result
            } catch (final JSONException jsonException) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                    "Unable to get Facebook user info. " + jsonException.getMessage() + "\n" + response,
                    jsonException);
        }
```